# Looping in a C-style For loop instead of using each

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

how can i loop through a `json file` using a `FOR` loop in groovy? I am able to do it with `.each` but i am in a situation/bug where i cannot use `.each` loops.

The json file is being read and parsed into an object.

The json looks like this:

```
{
    "workflows1": {
        "name": "/wf_multifolder",
        "file": "release1/wf_multifolder.XML",
        "folderNames": {
            "multifolder": "{{multifolder}}",
            "agent1": "{{agentx}}"
        }
    },
    "workflows2": {
        "name": "/wf_multifolder",
        "file": "release1/wf_multifolder.XML",
        "folderNames": {
            "multifolder": "{{multifolder}}",
            "agent1": "{{agentx}}"
        }
    }
}
```

Note: i can modify the json file, if need to make the process simpler.. All i am try to do is to loop throgh and extract the values for the keys.

Comment: Why can't you use each?

Comment: Because jenkins doesn't like each ... there is a limitation in this tool. I will paste the jira story # on this

Answer (score 1):

So given the json in a String like so:

```
def jsonText = '''{
    "workflows1": {
        "name": "/wf_multifolder",
        "file": "release1/wf_multifolder.XML",
        "folderNames": {
            "multifolder": "{{multifolder}}",
            "agent1": "{{agentx}}"
        }
    },
    "workflows2": {
        "name": "/wf_multifolder",
        "file": "release1/wf_multifolder.XML",
        "folderNames": {
            "multifolder": "{{multifolder}}",
            "agent1": "{{agentx}}"
        }
    }
}'''
```

You can just do:

```
import groovy.json.*

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonText)

for(entry in json) {
    println "$entry.key has file $entry.value.file"
}
```

to print:

```
workflows1 has file release1/wf_multifolder.XML
workflows2 has file release1/wf_multifolder.XML
```

Comment: thanks, but i think i will need to use a `counter`, so that i can iterate through the values of the say, workflow1 and then workflows2 .... so on.

Comment: I thought using the for in looping would cause problems with CPS?